# how I remove loading icon extjs 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have setTimout() on my grid store. Now store is loading after 5sec: when screen is loading, the screen will hang or jam. After screen reload, the screen is normal. Now tell me how can I remove that mask or etc??

I want screen reload but not show loading etc like that.

extjs4

Answer (score 1):

```
viewConfig:{
    loadMask:false
}
```

...

Comment: not working tell me one thing more i have gridpanel and window. i want to window over the grid when grid load or not. tell me how i can do it??

Comment: this is the correct way to disable loadmask - if its not working for you there must be other issues that can not be resolved without looking at the code. With regards to your window question: windows float be default so if you do not break the default config it will always float in front of the grid, unless that grid is inside another floating  window.